# using spring boot like postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I want to test my rest service, but without postman or jmeter. Is it possible get json response via spring boot?

Example:

```
@Annotation
JSON request(JSON url){
...
}
or
@Annotation
String request(String url){
...
}
```

Comment: Thats why we have Junits. Checkout https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `curl` from the commandline to test your restservice. Please see https://www.keycdn.com/support/popular-curl-examples for examples on how to do this.

In addition you might also want to write unittests using MockMvc. Please see https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/ for more information about testing the web layer.